# Sort list of strings by grouping on first char so that all those string from biggest group comes first, then those from second biggest group etc

Tags: java, sorting, group-by

I want to sort a list of strings in a way where the strings are sorted by the biggest group with respect to the first char, then the second char, then the third char etc.
The result should be that the strings at top of the list all belong to the biggest group when inspecting the first char. Within this group the top most should be the one whose second char belongs to the biggest group etc.

Here is an example of strings that are sorted the way I hope to achieve:

```
BYA
BYB
BYC
BXD
BXE
ABF
ABG
AAH
CAI
```

Note that all those strings starting with B comes first in the list because if we group on first char then the group of strings that begins with the letter B is the biggest. The sub-sort of the strings within this group are ordered by a similar logic: Those that have the the letter Y in the second place belongs to the biggest group for which reason they appear at the top.

I am unsure if this is best solved using an algoritm or a datastructure.
I have tried to use the Stream api and `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.counting` but this gives me a map from Character to all those strings beginning with that Character but I need to sort the list.

Comment: You are on the right track with `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.counting`. Once you have the map from character to count (e.g. `Map<Character,Long> counts;`), you can use it for sorting, i.e. `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(string -> counts.get(string.charAt(0)));` or `list.sort(Collections.reverseOrder((Comparator.comparing(string -> counts.get(string.charAt(0))));`

Comment: @Holger how does the above guarantee that the subgroups are also sorted in lexical order.  E.g.  ABF and ABG should be in ascending lexical order and not ABG followed by ABF.  Unless it is coincidental, the expected output has a regular lexical ordering in addition to the count.

Comment: @WJS there’s nothing said about lexical order but that would be the easier task. At the moment, it’s not even clear whether the second character based sub-ordering should use the frequency within the group or the total frequency among the entire list. The example is not sufficient to describe the task…

Comment: Holger's answer gave me just what I needed. Thanks. As hinted at by WJS's comment I also wanted to use lexicographical ordering whenever two groups have same size. This is why ABF comes before ABG: they are both part of the charAt(0)=A group, and part of the charAt(1)=B group. But to provide a consistent sorting I needed lexicographical sorting for the charAt(2) group since they both have the group size/count=1 for their 3rd char. Luckily this was an easy addition. Subordering happens within the group - fx: once Strings starting with B has been placed in top they remain at top.